# Use custom route for Laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

In the email verification routes, I wanted to change the route by adding the language in the URL. e.g., instead of having /email/verify, we want to have /fr/email/verify.

**Route**

```php
// Email Verification Routes
Route::get('{lg?}/email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')
    ->name('verification.notice')
    ->where('lg', '(fr)|(en)');
```

In the EnsureEmailIsVerified class, the users are to the "verification.notice" route:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
                !$request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::route('verification.notice');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Sadly, `Redirect::route('verification.notice')` redirects to /email/verify instead of en/email/verify (or fr/email/verify). What did I miss?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass the en or fr string to the redirect? IE: `Redirect::route('verification.notice', 'fr')` Your current redirect is working fine, since `{lg?}` isn't provided in the redirect, it goes to /email/verify

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my dev machine, but something along the lines of

```
Redirect::route('verification.notice', ['lg' => 'en'])
```

or

```
redirect()->route('profile', ['lg' => 'en']);
```

should work.